# Execute any script in double quotes

Tags: javascript, quotes

how can i run any javascript in double quotes ?
For example:

```
<input type="text" value="" />
```

i would like to execute an alert or any other code in the value = "" (double quotes). Like:

```
<input type="text" value="<script> onmouseover=alert(0);</script>" />
```

the code show as a string on page. So is there anyway to execute script in double quotes ?

Comment: I don't think you understand HTML well. You should learn about HTML, Javascript and the DOM first.

Comment: ok i will learn it . but can you answer this ?

Comment: What exactly do you want? You want to put javascript code in a value tag? Why? And how would it get activated? You put code in the onclick/onmouseover/on*** tag, or in a script (tag) and link it to the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I see, you probably want to do something like this:

```
<input type="text" onchange="try{eval(this.value)}catch(e){}" />
```

That inline script will attempt to execute what's in its value attribute every time the tag is changed (and you blur out of the element). The `try catch` block is so that anything that would normally not work won't get executed. The `eval` function parses a string and runs it as Javascript code.

You leave yourself open to many forms of attacks when you use `eval`, so unless this is for purely educational or in house purposes, I would advise you don't use this.

Comment: No i am not talking about the inline attributes. i am just asking, is there any way to execute any script in the quotes of value attribut ?

Comment: `eval` executes strings. You could make a function that gets the value attribute of an input element, and plug that in as the `eval` function's argument.

Answer (score 0):

The input object has its own events and you have to assign to them

For example to execute an alert when the mouse hovers over it:

```
<input type="text" value="testbox" onMouseOver="alert('testing');"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" onmouseover="alert(0);" />
```